# How to convert raw pdf from server to pdf document

Tags: java, pdf, kotlin

This is my code that converts the Retrofit HTTP ResponseBody to a raw String:

Method 1:

```
fun ByteArray.toHexString(): String {
    var cnt = ""
    var cnter = 0

    return this.joinToString(cnt) {
        if (cnter % 2 == 0)
            cnt = " "
        else
            cnt = ""
        cnter++
        String.format("%02x", it)
    }
}

fun convert() {
    val result = response.byteStream().readBytes(response.contentLength().toInt())
    val rawHtml = result.toHexString()
}
```

Method 1 result (snippet). It should have a whitespace after every 4th Byte:

```
255044462d312e340d0a25aaabacad0d0a312030206f626a0d0a3c3c0d0a2f4e616d65732032203020520d0a2f4f7574707574496e74656e7473205b3c3c0d0a2f446573744f757470757450726f66696c652033203020520d0a2f53202f4754535f50444641310d0a2f496e666f202863850eea75051264315790c769f97999de290d0a2f52656769737472794e616d652028290d0a2f4f7574707574436f6e646974696f6e2028290d0a2f54797065202f4f7574707574496e74656e740d0a2f4f7574707574436f6e646974696f6e4964656e746966696572202853a23adc3a21290d0a3e3e0d0a5d0d0a2f5669657765725072...
```

Method 2:

```
private fun getRawHTML(responseBody: ResponseBody): String {
    val bodyString = responseBody.byteStream()

    val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(bodyString, "iso-8859-1"), 16)
    val sb = StringBuilder()
    var line: String?

    line = reader.readLine()

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n")
        line = reader.readLine()
    }

    bodyString.close()

    return sb.toString()
}
```

Method 2 result (snippet):

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj
<<
/Title (þÿ��M��i���n��p��e��n��s��o��v��e��r��z��i��c�.��n��l)
/Creator (þÿ��w�m��p��d��f�� ��0��1��2��.��1��.��2)
/Producer (þÿ�t�� ��4����6)
/CreationDate (D:20181122184902+01'00')
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/Type /ExtGState
/SA true
/SM 0.02
/ca 1.0
/CA 1.0
/AIS false
/SMask /None>>
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
xí]MGr½Ï¯èó*å÷` )Ñ  ðÁðÁàZ^,FË{ðß÷{YÕ]
```

When scrolling down in this PDF it shows that the encoding is /Identity-H:

```
/Name /FBUKTZ+Verdana
/Type /Font
/Subtype /Type0
/BaseFont /FBUKTZ+Verdana
/Encoding /Identity-H
/ToUnicode 28 0 R
/DescendantFonts [29 0 R]
>>
```

Which charset corresponds to this?

I want to convert this to a PDF file that can be opened by Adobe acrobat reader and shows the original PDF. When I open a correct PDF file with sublime editor, I see this:

```
2550 4446 2d31 2e37 0a25 e2e3 cfd3 0a31
2030 206f 626a 0a3c 3c2f 416c 7465 726e
6174 652f 4465 7669 6365 5247 422f 4e20
332f 4c65 6e67 7468 2032 3631 352f 4669
```

Maybe I could rephrase the question to how can I convert the small snippet to this format? I'm using Kotlin and Java.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Kotlin program that downloads a PDF file from a server and saves it in a way that allows it to be opened in a PDF viewer:

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import java.io.FileOutputStream

fun savePDF(response: ResponseBody) {
    val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream("my.pdf")
    val data = response.byteStream().readBytes()
    fileOutputStream.write(data)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url("http://www.oracle.com/events/global/en/java-outreach/resources/java-a-beginners-guide-1720064.pdf")
        .build()
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
    val responseBody = response.body()
    if (responseBody != null) {
        savePDF(responseBody)
    }
}
```

Comment: With this solution I have to request write permissions to the Android user and we can't do that.

Comment: This is a program that you can run locally to understand how downloading PDF files works. If you actually need to send the file to another server, you can also do this, and you don't need any permissions for this.

Comment: Yeah but when opening the file it is not a PDF. This solution doesn't solve the question.

Comment: If you run this program and open my.pdf, it is a PDF. I can't give you a solution that will work with uploading data to your server without knowing anything about your server.